# Chinese phrase for 'stripped of one's rank'

Tags: usage, vocabulary

In the movie, 'Wolf Warrior 2', the protagonist was stripped of his ranks before being sent to military jail.

How could the stripping of rank be described concisely in mandarin? I was thinking something along the lines of 扯官。

Comment: http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=stripped+of+rank, e.g.  3.  The officer was stripped of his rank for misconduct.
 那军官因行为不端被削去了军衔。

Comment: 剥夺/消除/撤消/消去/免去 军衔

Comment: English has a number of synonyms for "strip so. of sth.", however as a matter of collocation they cannot be interchanged freely w/o making the phrase sound uncommon,
users would suggest that collocation is at least as important in Chinese, therefore why not search web with each of the 1st 3 verbs of comment #2 followed by  军衔, to see which is commonly used ( jukuu justifies the last 2 消去/免去, see comment #1)

Comment: Wikipedia, Wolf warriors 2, 战狼2, https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%88%B0%E7%8B%BC2  has 冷锋因伤人被开除军籍并被判监禁。坐牢期间，...  bkrs: 军籍
1) military status
2) one's name on an army roll; military register
保留军籍 retain one’s military status 
thus in Chinese it may be more common to say 被开除军籍 = "be thrown out of the military"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

免职：removed from position;

降级: demoted;

免级: remove ranks (though not necessarily "stripped" of ranks)

Answer (score 0):

More like '被剥夺了‘ or an officer '被免去军阶'

他被剥夺政治权利5年。

Answer (score 0):

"被免去了军衔" sounds best to me. "军阶" is less commonly used than "军衔". "剥夺" doesn't convey the implication that the rank is taken away by 上级 (authority, upper-level leader) like "被免去" does. 剥夺 sounds more like its taken away unmorally, as in "剥夺了我的自由" (forcefully take away my freedom). So it has the implication that the guy is actually a good guy but somehow some bad people decide to frame on him and take away his rank.

Answer (score 0):

撤职：to be dismissed of one’s duty or rank due to abuse of power or violations;

撤职查办：to be dismissed and investigated (for criminal transgressions)

In comparison, 免职 is a relatively neutral term, and one can be 免职 due to or not due to any reasons. And 剥夺 means taking away one’s freedom or right.